# HTML Textarea in JointJS SVG shapes

Tags: svg, jointjs

I'm trying to place a HTML textarea in a SVG shape using JointJS. I followed their tutorial (https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements) and some advice I found here.

[image]

Sorry can't embedd images yet due to reputation.

Generally it works ok and when the shape is dragged around the textarea follows nicely. However, when the underlying paper is moved only the SVG shape moves. I assume this kind of movement is not taken care of in the update function since the position paremeters of the SVG don't change, but I can't figure out how to enable this.

Also once selected the textarea stays selected event when the user does other things. Any advice how to solve these problems would be really appreaciated.

Comment: create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue and edit the question to contain it.

Comment: I will create that example also to figure out if anything in the rest of the code interfers. Takes a bit of coding though and will take a while. I thought meanwhile someone who used JointsJS for similar things could give me some feedback whether that is default behaviour if you follow the example in the linked tutorial